# What exactly is a tensor product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, quantum-groups

This is a beginner's question on what exactly is a tensor product, in laymen's term, for a beginner who has just learned basic group theory and basic ring theory.

I do understand from wikipedia that in some cases, the tensor product is an outer product, which takes two vectors, say $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$, and outputs a matrix $\textbf{uv}^T$. ($\textbf{u}$ being a $m\times 1$ column vector and $\textbf{v}$ being a $n\times 1$ column vector)

How about more general cases of tensor products, e.g. in the context of quantum groups?

Sincere thanks.

Comment: What kinds of objects are you taking the tensor product of?

Comment: Look at this http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/tensors3.html

Comment: +1 for ehsanmo's fantastic  link. The explanations there are due to Timothy Gowers, a Fields medalist and one of the outstanding mathematicians of this century (the linked page  modestly does  not mention the author !)

Comment: I would add to the list of references two expository articles on the tensor product by Keith Conrad. The link to the web page containing all his expository stuff is this:http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/. They are a great resource for algebra. The relevant articles are under the section titled Linear/ Multilinear Algebra.

Comment: As a believer in simplicity, I've posted what may be the simplest P.O.V. on this question below.  Definitely my answer is not the last word though---i.e. there's lots more to know.

Comment: I don't think tensor products live in layman's terms, outside of seeing examples. For instance, ${\mathbf C} \otimes_{\mathbf R} {\mathbf R}[x] \cong {\mathbf C}[x]$ and ${\mathbf R}[x] \otimes_{\mathbf R} {\mathbf R}[y] \cong {\mathbf R}[x,y]$. *Everybody* finds tensor products hard the first (or second?) time through and I don't think there is a way around that. Someone once said tensor products are the hardest thing in mathematics. While that is definitely not true, I think it's fair to say they are the hardest thing in basic mathematics. I don't think you can "get" them (contd.)

Comment: just from having a layman's idea about what they are. I'm not trying to be discouraging, but rather to emphasize that you're going to have to put in a lot of work and time for tensor products to be something you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to study a mathematical object, whether it is a set, manifold, group, vector space, whatever, it is often fruitful to look at natural collections of functions on that space.

Roughly, the purpose of the tensor product, $\otimes$, is to make the following statement true:
$$\text{functions}(X \times Y) = \text{functions}(X)\otimes \text{functions}(Y)$$

The specific details about which spaces of functions to choose depend on the type of mathematical object you are interested in.

Here's a pdf that explains it better than I can,
http://abel.math.harvard.edu/archive/25b_spring_05/tensor.pdf

Comment: The link does not work anymore. However, I feel that https://www.math3ma.com/blog/the-tensor-product-demystified by Tai-Danae Bradley will help a lot of people.

Comment: Is the cross inside the parenthesis on the left term a Cartesian product?

Comment: A working link to the PDF given above can now be found at
http://abel.math.harvard.edu/archive/25b_spring_05/tensor.pdf

Comment: @jhu Thanks, updated the post with the new link!

Answer (score 4):

The difference between an ordered pair of vectors and a tensor product of two vectors is this:

If you multiply one of the vectors by a scalar and the other by the reciprocal of that scalar, you get a **different** ordered pair of vectors, but the **same** tensor product of two vectors.

Similarly with an ordered triple of vectors and a tensor product of three vectors, etc.

Comment: I've thought along these lines before (tensors are combos of vectors with special rules), but always ran into the same intuitive stumbling block. Why is it that some elements of a tensor space are pure and can be represented as $w=x \otimes y$, whereas others are composite and can only be built from sums of pure tensors? I sort of gave up on thinking of it that way, but maybe you have some insight..?

Comment: I don't have a simple answer to that right now....  Maybe later?

Comment: There is a simple answer: just think about multivariable polynomials! Let's just look at polynomials in two variables. Some of them are monomials, or more generally products $f(x)g(y)$, but most multivariable polynomials are *not* of that (separable) form. The theory of polynomials in two variables is more than the theory of things that factor as $f(x)g(y)$. This in fact is a special instance of tensor products, since $F[x] \otimes_F F[y] \cong F[x,y]$ for any field $F$.

Comment: Another point on the subtlety of the phenomenon of tensors that are not pure (elementary, monomial, separable, whatever you want to call them) is that they are show up in the mathematical description of entanglement in quantum mechanics. That is, in QM the combined state space for two quantum systems is a (completed) tensor product of the original two spaces, and trying to wrap your head around entangled states of two particles is the conundrum of trying to wrap your head around the idea that some tensors are not pure.

Comment: There's a second way two unequal ordered pairs can correspond to the same pure tensor that I think is worth keeping in mind: for vector spaces $V$, $W$ and non-zero vectors $v\in V\setminus\{0\}$, $w\in W\setminus\{0\}$ the pairs $(0,0)$, $(v,0)$, and $(0,w)$ are all different, but the pure tensors $0\otimes0$, $v\otimes0$, and $0\otimes w$ are all the same.