# What does the tensor symbol "$\otimes$" (or whatever this symbol is) do?

Tags: soft-question

I encountered the symbol "$\otimes$" in [a Numberphile video about the Dehn Invariant](https://youtu.be/eYfpSAxGakI), and I have no clue what it means.

> What, in layman terms, does this symbol do?

I'm not all that experienced in maths and often fail to understand the jargon used in the descriptions of what the tensor symbol does and what a "tensor product" is.

Comment: How about trying to Google "tensor product" ...

Comment: Do you know what a *vector space* (or *linear space*) is?

Comment: Previously: [What exactly is a tensor product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/144501/856), [What is a tensor product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/532780/856) An article recommended at both links: [How to lose your fear of tensor products](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/tensors3.html) by Fields medalist Timothy Gowers.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/an-introduction-to-tensors

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics [vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)) are abstract entities that like the vectors used in physics to represent forces can be summed or multiplied by a scalar (i.e. a number).

A [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) is roughly speaking a set of vectors that contains every sum of any two vectors in it and every multiple of every vector in it.

If we have two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ we can build up a new vector space $V\times W$ considering *pairs* of vectors: an element in $V\times W$ will be a pair
$$
(v,w)\qquad v\in V,\quad w\in W.
$$
The tensor product $V\otimes W$ is a different and a bit subtler way to pair vectors in $V$ with vectors in $W$. A basic element in $V\otimes W$ is something denoted
$$
v\otimes w.
$$
The main difference between pairs and tensors is that while the pairs
$$
(\lambda v,w)\qquad
(v,\lambda w)
$$
give different elements in $V\times W$ there is an actual equality
$$
(\lambda v)\otimes w=v\otimes(\lambda w)
$$
as elements in $V\otimes W$ (in the above $\lambda$ is any scalar).

The basic reason to introduce tensor products is to reduce, so to speak, the theory of multilinear functions to the theory of linear functions. For instance, there's a characterization of the determinant of a square matrix that uses the language of tensor products.

Comment: The Dehn invariant lives in the space $\mathbb R\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb R/(2\pi)$, which is a tensor product of $\mathbb Z$-modules, not of vector spaces. The idea is similar though.

Comment: @Kalua, given that $R$-modules, for a general ring $R$, are a natural generalization of vector spaces things aren't indeed that different. In any event, in order to grasp the basic ideas about tensor products starting with vector spaces is undoubtedly better.

Comment: @AndreaMori thank you for your answer. I do think that I'll need more of a background in the field in which tensors are used (not from you, just as I may learn about the field eventually through my education) before I can fully understand their operator.